# re-render in react native- issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, rendering

I have this code in react native, if user click yes to delete the item from list. but the item still in the bag until refresh it ! 
how can I do re-render when clicked delete?

```js
  const bagProducts = this.props.allProducts;
    const productId = this.props.deleteProductAction(this.props.id).id;
    var result = bagProducts.filter(x => {
      return x.id == productId;
    })[0];
```

```js
  <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.bagItemButtons}
            onPress={() => {
              Alert.alert(
                "Alert",
                "Are you sure wnat do delete ?",
                [
                  { text: "NO", onPress: () => console.log("Cancel pressed") },
                  {
                    text: "Yes",
                    onPress: () => {
                      bagProducts.splice(result, 1);
                    }
                  }
                ],
                { cancelable: true }
              );
            }}
          >
            <Text style={styles.bagItemButtonText}>{t("delete")}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 4):

Put your list Item in State and update the state it will render the list

Answer (score 0):

Your bagProducts should be held in the local state and then you run a setState to modify bagProducts. That will cause a re-render.

Comment: const bagProducts = this.props.allProducts;
my bagProducts is array of objects that I delete item from it

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you are rendering the `bagProducts`.

But if you want to re-render the bags,you need to update the state.

Assuming `state` object.

add event handler to update bags,

```
updateBags=()=>{

    bagProducts.splice(result, 1);

    this.setState(({bagProducts}));
}
```

call `updateBags` on onPress

```
onPress: this.updateBags //onPress should be like this.call updateBags
```

Comment: bagProduts the army of object that i will delete from it. 
  const bagProducts = this.props.allProducts;
    const productId = this.props.deleteProductAction(this.props.id).id;
    var result = bagProducts.filter(x => {
      return x.id == productId;
    })[0];

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
        this.forceUpdate()
```

method at the end of your delete function.

Comment: This is pretty nasty. It will work BUT if you are using forceUpdate() then you have missed the point of react.

Comment: Yes but I already had an error who tell me that it's impossible to render because the state change